# Are there application fees for PhD positions in Europe?

Tags: phd, application, europe, fees

I'm new to the applying process and I'd like to ask a simple question. Does a PhD position in European universities require an application fee?

Comment: Why not check the websites of the programs you are interested in applying to?

Comment: Europe consists of 40+ countries and, although the Bologna process started to "harmonize the Europe higher education", the answer depends on the country - there is no answer to this question in this generality.

Comment: I applied to about 10 European universities for my PhD and only one (Oxford) charged a fee. But anyway, as others have said, it's not standardised so apply and you will find out.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely dependent on the manner in which the PhD program is handled. If it is a purely research position that is applied for like a job, then there is typically no fee associated with it. However, if it is part of a "program" and involves coursework and other requirements, then there may be a fee associated with a formal application. You'll have to check the announcement of the position to be certain.